# IList<T> doesn't seem to contain the method "Remove"

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an instance of MyClass, defined as:

```
public partial class MyClass  
{
    public virtual string PropertyName1 { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Class2List> Class2Lists{ get; set; }
}
```

I use reflection to try and find the `Remove` method:

```
object obj1 = myClassObject;
Type type = obj1.GetType();
Type typeSub = type.GetProperty("Class2Lists").PropertyType; 

//this method can not find
MethodInfo methodRemove = typeSub.GetMethod("Remove");

// this method can find
MethodInfo methodRemove = typeSub.GetMethod("RemoveAt");

// there is no "Remove" method in the list
MethodInfo[] methodRemove = typeSub.GetMethods();
```

But I can't find the `Remove` method, why?

Answer (score 3):

- `IList<T>` defines `RemoveAt()`, but it doesn't define `Remove()`.
- `IList<T>` inherits from `ICollection<T>`, which defines `Remove()`.

An example how to retrieve the correct `MethodInfo`:

```
Type typeWithRemove = typeSub.GetInterfaces ()
    .Where ( i => i.GetMethod ( "Remove" ) != null )
    .FirstOrDefault ();

if ( typeWithRemove != null )
{
    MethodInfo methodRemove = typeWithRemove.GetMethod ( "Remove" ); 
}
```